# CodeIgniter PHP error Login Form

Tags: codeigniter, authentication, php

I am working on a login form using code igniter. I can get the form to display alright but when I click to login I get the following error displayed:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: CI_DB_mysql_driver::$query

Filename: models/membership_model.php

Line Number: 8
```

This is m membership_model.php file

```
    class Membership_model extends CI_Model{

    function validate(){
        $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
        $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
        $this->$query = $this->db->query->get('members');

        if($query->num_rows != 0){
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

This is my login.php file which is my main controller.

```
class Login extends CI_CONTROLLER{


function index()
{
    $data['main_content'] = 'login_form';
    $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
}

function validate_credentials()
{
    //load model to query db
    $this->load->model('membership_model');
    $query = $this->membership_model->validate();

    if($query){ //if credentials validated
        $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'is_logged_in' => true

            );

            $this ->session->set_userdata($data);
            redirect('site/members_area');
    }

    else{ //if not validated load login form again.
        $this->index();

    }

}
```

This is a screen shot of the error message I am getting

[image: screen showing error message]

Any ideas what could be going wrong? I haven't a clue! I've looked on the internet but nothing seems to help me. Has anyone encountered this problem. I've been following this tutorial video but it is using an older version of code igniter so I've been making changes as I go.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-fLtTRYQX0M
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-6-login/

Comment: Do you have active record enabled?

Comment: I don't think so, will i find that within the config file?

Comment: It's in your `application/database.php` file and should be this `$active_record = TRUE;` Also is this the first time you are doing database queries in your app, as in have you been able to connect successfully previously and retrieve data?

Comment: It is enabled and previously I had no problems querying db and connecting to it. This is a fresh install of CI however as I am trying to compile everything from my other apps to make one single app if that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function validate(){
    $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
    $this->$query = $this->db->query->get('members');

    if($query->num_rows != 0){
        return true;
    }
}
```

should be:

```
function validate()
{
    $array = array(
        'username' => $this->input->post('username'), 
        'password' => md5($this->input->post('password')));
    $query = $this->db->get_where('members', $array); 
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Note: `get_where()` may be called `getwhere()` if you are using an older version of CI

Btw you shouldn't be using MD5 for hashing your passwords. You should be using BCrypt as MD5 is insecure.

Comment: I changed it as you suggested but to no avail. I do see how that was causing a problem though. Careless on my part. I posted another question which is in some ways linked to my problem here because now the above problem is not being seen.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14866158/codeigniter-404-bad-request-error#comment20840624_14866158

Comment: You can use the `get_where()` method. I'll redo your code to use it.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful! I appreciate that big time but for some reason I am getting a 404. I created a new question outlining this problem.

Answer (score 0):

First the obvious, are you loading the database library?

Second,  why are you appending get() after query()?

i.e.

```
$this->db->query->get('members');
```

query() is a standalone function whose example says it is supposed to be used like this:

```
$query = $this->db->query('YOUR QUERY HERE');
```

whereas get() is part of active record.

```
$query = $this->db->get('mytable');
```

or in your case:

```
$query = $this->db->get('members');
```