# CodeIgniter 404 Bad request error

Tags: codeigniter, http-status-code-404, php

I'm working with codeIgniter. I am making a login form which checks the members details with the database.

However when I click to login I get this error message:

```
The requested URL /waitronmain/login.php/login/validate_credentials was not found on this server.
```

However this is my login.php file and as you can see validate_credentials() does exist.

```
class Login extends CI_Controller{


function index()
{
    $data['main_content'] = 'login_form';
    $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
}

function validate_credentials()
{
    //load model to query db
    $this->load->model('membership_model');
    $query = $this->membership_model->validate();

    if($query){ //if credentials validated
        $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'is_logged_in' => true

            );

            $this ->session->set_userdata($data);
            redirect('site/members_area');
    }

    else{ //if not validated load login form again.
        $this->index();

    }

}
```

}

Any idea what's going wrong? I should be going on to the 'members_area' page as I know the details I am entering are correct.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Whats with the `/login.php/index.php` part of the url? Is that your actual url? Anyway, the problem is possibly that you are using a underbar `_` in your url. You should be using a dash `validate-credentials`. I don't think a controllers function names can have a dash in them, so you will need to use a route (routes.php) to connect the url `validate-credentials` with the method `validate_credentials`.

Comment: Sorry about the messy URL that was due to not setting the proper index page in the 'config.php' file. I updated the URL in my question. I am unsure as to how I can use the 'routes.php' file to connect the url. Can you give example?

Comment: Why is it named `login.php`? It should be named `index.php` as that is your main file which handles all your requests and will properly load the Login class.

Comment: I changed my default index page to `login.php` instead of `index.php`. That is why I have it named that way.

Comment: I'll be back in awhile, I have to head out, don't want you thinking I ditched out =o). If this isn't solved by the time I get back I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Were you able to set up a route?

Comment: @Jeemusu I did this `$route['validateCredentials'] = "login";` although I'm not sure If it is correct..the problem remains when running the app

Comment: With your original set up you could of done something like this: `$route['login/validate-credentials'] = "login/validate_credentials";`

Comment: What is the url in the login form action attribute?

Comment: form action -> `http://localhost/waitronmain/login.php/login/validateCredentials`

Answer (score 0):

what is this??

/waitronmain`/login.php/`login/validate_credentials

login.php should be not in url i think you should do:

```
/waitronmain/login/validate_credentials
```

(assuming you removed index.php from urls and you are inside the waitronmain/ root )